# Javascript bind an call

Tags: javascript

I came across following code. Trying to understand what exactly it's doing. It seems like script file is intentionally obfuscated.

```
var d=Function.prototype.bind,
e=Function.prototype.call,
f=e.bind(d,e),
```

which kinds of translates to

```
var f = Function.prototype.call.bind(Function.prototype.bind, Function.prototype.call)
```

Looking at MDN documentation, bind accepts additional parameters passed to function. Does this mean, whenever variable f is used, its going to get Function.prototype.call as a first parameter? How does setting "this" to Function.prototype.bind help?

Comment: `.call` executes the function `this` points to.

Comment: Yes, it's intentionally confusing, it's obviously meant to be a puzzle.

Comment: I guess `f(fn, a, b, c)` executes `fn` with the arguments a b c

Comment: If you could post more surrounding code, that would be more helpful in determining the actual use of the code.

As it stands, it seems to be making `f()` return a new version of `Function.prototype.call` every time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal way that `Function.prototype.call` is used is like:

```
functionName.call(thisvalue, arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

When the `call` method is invoked, it gets the function named by `functionName` as its `this` context (just like any other method invocation does), and it calls it.

In your code, we're using `bind()` to create a new function that has its `this` context and first argument bound to specific values. The function is `Function.prototype.call`, its `this` context is `Function.prototype.bind`, and its first argument is `Function.prototype.call`. So doing

```
x = f(something)
```

will be equivalent to calling

```
x = Function.prototype.bind.call(Function.prototype.call, something)
```

This is then equivalent to:

```
x = Function.prototype.call.bind(something)
```

So `x` is also a function -- it's the `call` method with its `this` context bound to `something. So calling

```
x(1, 2, 3)
```

is equivalent to

```
something.call(1, 2, 3)
```

I sure hope I got this right, it's really convoluted, like Adventure's maze of twisty little passages, all different.

Comment: I think you are right. Looking at the pattern of usage, it's actually making sense after your explanation

Comment: I wrote the answer and it doesn't make sense to me!